# How to pass Google Drive Credential to a WebRequest?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am a beginner of C#.

I would like to load a thumbnail to a PictureBox within a window form [here](https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w180&id=[pic%20id]).

And my approach is using webrequest to open the path above and get the image from the response.

However, it's doesn't work since I do not know how to set the credential to webrequest from pass the google drive credential.

It is great if someone can help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you may want to start using the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).

```
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

using System.Net;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /// <summary>
  /// Print a file's metadata.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="service">Drive API service instance.</param>
  /// <param name="fileId">ID of the file to print metadata for.</param>
  public static void printFile(DriveService service, String fileId) {
    try {
      File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();

      Console.WriteLine("Title: " + file.Title);
      Console.WriteLine("Description: " + file.Description);
      Console.WriteLine("MIME type: " + file.MimeType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Download a file and return a string with its content.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="authenticator">
  /// Authenticator responsible for creating authorized web requests.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="file">Drive File instance.</param>
  /// <returns>File's content if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
  public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(
      IAuthenticator authenticator, File file) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl)) {
      try {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
        authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
          return response.GetResponseStream();
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine(
              "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
          return null;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }

  //...

}
```

The [parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#parameters) (Parameter Name, Variable type and Description) are described in the documentation.

You can read [this guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) for the implementation of authentication and authorization in your code.

**OAuth 2.0**

> This document describes OAuth 2.0, when to use it, how to acquire
>   client IDs, and how to use it with the Google API Client Library for
>   .NET.

as you go along the documentation, you will see the given [sample code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications) that will serve as reference for your implementation.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Books.v1;
using Google.Apis.Books.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Books.ListMyLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample which demonstrates how to use the Books API.
    /// https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started
    /// <summary>
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Books API Sample: List MyLibrary");
            Console.WriteLine("================================");
            try
            {
                new Program().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { BooksService.Scope.Books },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
            }

            // Create the service.
            var service = new BooksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Books API Sample",
                });

            var bookshelves = await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List().ExecuteAsync();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```